# Unable to access shares on laptop when it's connected via WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have a domain-joined laptop which I'm attempting to access from any other computer on the domain (in this case an administrative share `\\LAPTOP\D$`).

This has worked since forever while the laptop has been connected to the network via Ethernet cable. But my physical topology has changed recently, and now I'm forced to connect using Wi-Fi. Since I made this (seemingly minor) change, other machines on the domain can't reach any share or even the machine itself `\\LAPTOP\`.

I've verified that file sharing is turned on, and I tried enabling FIPS as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1211107). But it's still failing, even after cycling the connection to pick up the new FIPS setting.

It's worth noting that even though other computers on the domain can't access the laptop via File Explorer, PowerShell, etc., they can successfully ping it.

How can I access the laptop's shares while it's connected via Wi-Fi?

Comment: is the word `LAPTOP` the actual string you put in or the IP address of your laptop? Have you tried using your laptop's IP from other computer?

Comment: I'm using the machine's NETBIOS name. The actual word `LAPTOP` here is a pseudonym for safety/security reasons. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. I checked my DNS just now and it wasn't synchronized with DHCP for the new lease. I updated that and I sailed right in. I'm feeling a bit silly that I didn't check that earlier. Thank you.

Comment: Is perhaps the router set to separate the WiFi segment from the Ethernet segment?

Comment: @harrymc — It turned out to be an outdated DNS entry. Once I fixed that, everything worked squeaky clean. Thanks.

Comment: @someuser — Care to formulate that into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Windows device name to access your share from other device, try first using the server's IP address. If that works, it tells you it may have something to do with your directory service. There could be another device having the same name, for example or the name is not propagated some how.

If SMB access via IP also does not work, try to telnet to your server's SMB TCP port 445 and see if it connects. If not, try starting some TCP service (say, Python HTTP Server) to isolate issue, it could still be a firewall issue.